# iPhone app switching

Tags: iphone, linker, switch-statement, switching

Is it possible to run an iPhone app from your own app?
For example when you press a button in your app, the iPhone switches to another app.
If so, how would you do this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but the developer of the app being switched to will have to have specified a URL protocol handler. For more information on those, look [here](http://www.mobileorchard.com/apple-approved-iphone-inter-process-communication/). If it has specified a protocol handler, you can use the `openURL:` method to open the URL. Example (opens the Phone app and dials a number:

`[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"tel://123456789"]];`

The easiest way to make sure this works is if you're the developer of the app being launched.

Answer (score 2):

"You can register URL types for your application that include custom URL schemes. A custom URL scheme is a mechanism through which third-party applications can interact with each other and with the system. Through a custom URL scheme, an application can make its services available to other applications."

[Implementing Custom URL Schemes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ApplicationEnvironment/ApplicationEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH7-SW50)

Take a look at "Registering Custom URL Schemes" and "Handling URL Requests"